# Why after that the JQuery slideToggle() function is called the tbody have a display:block setted and its width appear compressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I am pretty new in JavaScript and JQuery and I am going crazy with the following problem, I will try to explain:

I have a page in which I show two accordions, this page:

[image]

Ok, as you can see in the screenshot, there are 2 accordions tab (the second one is collapsed) that contains 2 buttons (the left bottom corner).

This is the HTML strucuture:

```
<!-- FIRST ACCORDION: -->
<div id="ricercaFlussi">
    <table class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls">
        <thead class="opening active">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <img class="imgAccordion" src="img/arrow_down.gif"/>
                Ricerca Flussi (la funzione e' consentita per flussi inferiori alle 300 fatture)
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="expanded">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100em;">
                    <table class="standard-table-cls" style="margin-left: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important;">

                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%">Numero di giorni dalla pubblicazione</td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <input type="text" maxlength="3" size="5" name="giorni">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        ......................................................
                        ......................................................
                        ......................................................
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="bottoneDiv">
                        <input class="bottone" type="text" readonly
                               value="Conferma" onclick="Javascript: loadingPopUp(); return ricercaFlusso();"
                               onMouseOver="'Conferma';return true"/>
                        <input class="bottone" type="text" readonly
                               value="Cancella" onclick="Javascript: loadingPopUp(); pulisciFormRicercaFlusso()"
                               onMouseOver="'Cancella';return true"/>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- SECOND ACCORDION: -->
<div id="ricercaFatture">
    <table class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls">

        <thead class="opening">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <img class="imgAccordion" src="img/arrow.gif"/>
                Ricerca Fatture
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="expanded" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100em;">

                <!--<div id="ricercaFlussiHeader" class="accordion-pane-header" onclick="Javascript: visualizzaPannelli(true, false);">Ricerca Flussi</div>-->
                <div id="ricercaFattureContent" class="accordion-pane-content" style="">


                    <table class="standard-table-cls" style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;">

                        <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%">
                                <input type="hidden" name="pkCodaSelezionata" value="<%=pkCoda%>" readonly>
                                Numero Fattura
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" maxlength="12" size="14" name="numeroFattura"
                                       value="<%=numeroFattura%>">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        .....................................................
                        .....................................................
                        .....................................................
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


                    <div class="bottoneDiv">
                        <input class="bottone" type="text" readonly
                               value="Conferma" onclick='Javascript: loadingPopUp(); return ricercaFattura(null)'
                               onMouseOver="'Conferma';return true"/>
                        <input class="bottone" type="text" readonly
                               value="Cancella" onclick="Javascript: loadingPopUp(); pulisciFormRicercaFattura()"
                               onMouseOver="'Cancella';return true"/>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>


</div>
```

And there is this **JQuery** script that is used for open and close the previous accordion tabs:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("thead.opening").click(function () {
            var tbodyElement = $(this).next();

            $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
                $(this).prev("thead.opening").toggleClass("active");
                $("thead.opening").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow.gif");
                $("thead.active").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow_down.gif");
            });

            //$(this).next().css('display', 'none');

            return false;
        });
    });
```

So what this JQuery script does is: when the user clikc on a **thead** it collapse or open its **tbody** calling the **slideToggle()** JQuery function that simply **display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion**.

It works fine (the tbody related to the clicked tab are correctly opened and hide) but the problem is that if I close the tab and then I open it again (or if I open a tab for the first time, as happens for the second tab titled **Ricerca Fatture**) the buttons are shifted on the left, this is the secreenshot of wath I obtain:

[image]

In this case I close and open both the tabs, so if you compared this screenshot with the previous one you can see that the buttons are shifted on the left.

Trying to analyze the DOM with FireBug I found that.

Before close and open a tab I have that the **tbody** containing the content of the:

```
<tbody class="expanded">
```

When I click on an opened tab (click on the **thead) I obtain that the **tbody** is:

```
<tbody class="expanded" style="display: none;">
```

and so the tbody is correctly hidden.

But if now I click on a the **thead** of an hidden **tbody** this **tbody** is changed (by the previous slideToggle() function) into:

and I obtain that all the **td** into the **tbody** have a smaller width so the buttons are not in the left bottom corner (all the content of the tbody is "compressed"), this is the FireBug screenshot where you can see what happens:

[image]

As you can see the **tbody** content have a smaller width.

I can't understand why !!! It seems that it may depend by the setted **style="display: block;"** because if in FireBug I try to change this value in

```
style="display: auto;"
```

it returns to be displayed correctly !!!

So I tryed to add this JQuery function to the previous one:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("thead.opening").click(function () {
            var tbodyElement = $(this).next();

            $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
                $(this).prev("thead.opening").toggleClass("active");
                $("thead.opening").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow.gif");
                $("thead.active").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow_down.gif");
            });

            //$(this).next().css('display', 'none');

            return false;
        });

         $("thead.opening").click(function () {
         alert("INTO second function");
         $(this).next().css('width', '10000000 em');
         alert(modified);
         $(this).next().css('width', '10000000 em');
         $(this).next().css('display', 'auto');

         alert($(this).next().css('display'));
         });

    });
```

My idea is, after that the **slideToggle()** open a tab (and set the **style="display: block;"** on my **tbody**) I take the same **tbody** and I set the **style="display: auto;"**

But it can't work because after that I open a tab I have that it still remains:

**style="display: block;"**

and not:

**style="display: auto;"**

as I expect. The strange thing is that if in the previous script I try to set the **display: none** value instead the **display:auto**, by:

```
$(this).next().css('display', 'none');
```

it works as I expext and the **tbody** is always hidden.

So, what could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue and prevent that the **style="display: block;"** on the re-opened **tbody** cause that its contente have a compressed width? I am going crazy trying to find a solution

Tnx

Comment: Hello Andrea, could you add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @MisterJ it is pretty difficult because it is a JSP page with a huge CSS

Answer (score -1):

So this is a little difficult by just setting the CSS. What you will have to do is overwrite jQuery styles by giving **'display : auto !important'** in css and give it a class. Now use this class while toggling, meaning that when you call slide toggle to close then remove this class and if slide toggle is writing as display block that time add this class so that !important takes more precedence.

Comment: Tryied, don't works !!! I still have the same problem. It remains setted as: display: block

Comment: Then the best possible way to go is by sending a callback on complete and changing the css.
http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/
On complete the css would be set to display:block so you overwrite by making it display:auto on complete of the slidetoggle method by sending a callback function.